# Anaconda environment in Python 3.6 unable to install PySide & Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, pyside

Having [downloaded](https://github.com/mmolero/SimNDT) a rather complex (well complex to me) program from github, that appear to have been working 3 years ago I tried to run it in an Anaconda Python 2.7 environment (documentation is written in 2014 and 2.7 was the latest version then) but I don't get past the first hurdle, installing `PySide` (or getting Spyder to work in an environment).

- I've tried to install
  `conda install -c conda-forge pyside==1.2.2`
  (the program recommends 1.2.2 but apparently this not available anymore through anaconda, no clue in how to install this)
- I've tried to install pyside without specifying the version since the version 1.2.2 is not available but 1.2.4 is
  `conda install -c conda-forge pyside`
- I've checked that I am actually in the 2.7 (and later repeated in the 3.6) environment when I try to install it
  `conda activate MyEnvironment`

But this still returns following errors:

```
>Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
>Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
>Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
>Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>Solving environment: |
>Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
>This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abor/
failed

>UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

>Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

I've tried to change the imports to PyQT5 and run it in Python 3.8 but that was unsuccessful (no surprises there).

I'm perfectly able to install other packages in the environment (e.g. `numpy` or PySide2) but not Spyder.

Ideally I would like to manage to run this program in a 2.7 environment to see if it's helpful, alternatively I wouldn't mind tips on shortcuts to update the entire program to 3.8.

Comment: 1.2.2 does exist in PyPI, so one possibility is to install it via `pip install PySide==1.2.2`: https://pypi.org/project/PySide/1.2.2/

Many of your errors is likely due to deprecation and incompatibility. As far as python 3.x, this might be the library that you want to use: https://pypi.org/project/PySide6

Comment: What exactly is the issue with Spyder? You seem to mostly focus on `PySide`

Comment: @astrochun
Thnx, one step ahead. pip install works when I excecute it from the win cmd shell in the python 2.7 environment. If I open python from the shell and import PySide it doesn't give any errors so it is actually installed. Now I'm onto the next bit of trouble

- I tried installing Spyder form the shell `conda install -c conda-forge spyder` that provided errors (unavailable something something), I tried through anaconda navigator, didn't work. I've updated and reversed conda and now I managed to install Spyder through navigator.

Comment: @astrochun, however something is still off, if I run Spyder in the Python 2.7 environment it doesn't know PySide
`import PySide
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-3267ca000ac0>", line 1, in <module>
    import PySide

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'`

And if I try to run Spyder from the CMD it doens't recognize Spyder anymore.
`>>> Spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Spyder' is not defined`

It appears like there would be 2 entities python in cmd shell and python in anaconda.

Comment: However their environments have the same name, I only created that environment 1 time and it appeared automatically in the anaconda navigator, so it is not a case that there are actually 2 different entities running.

Comment: Spyder comes with conda navigator so trying to manually install it creates a variety of problems as I would expect. I don't use spyder myself. You really should check which versions of spyder you're using and their paths. The wrong one might be used.

Comment: Honestly I think the path of least resistance is just to forget 2.7 and move on to 3.x and develop and do stuff there. There's no guarantee on any easy installation/stability with all these old libraries and UI. You're just be doing patch work.

Comment: @astrochun it is the only logical explanation (there are a few other threads that have similar problems on here but apparently no solution) but I can't figure out which Spyder I'm calling. Anyway, thank you, I'll put more effort into python 3.8.x &PySide6, if I manage I'll throw the code on github.